# Datatable ImportRow

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

```
DataSet dsUdpated = new DataSet()
DataTable dtUpdated = dsUpdated.Tables.Add();
dtUpdated = dsOriginal.Tables[0].Clone();   // Guarenteed ds.Tables[0] has rows
dsUpdate.Tables[0].ImportRow(row); // row is one of the filtered row in
```

But the ImportRow doesnt seem to add the rows!. dsUpdate.Tables[0] doesnt contain the row. But a row is added. Please help!

Comment: From where's you are importing the records? Is dsOriginal is the table from where's you are importing the row. But there is no code for such kind of operation.

Comment: @soandos  - The row is added.. with one empty  column and value.  @avirk - I kept the code minimal and dsOriginal is loaded with data!

Comment: What happens if you clone dsOriginal instead of just making a new DataSet? Does the rows get added then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you're doing wrong.

```
DataTable dtUpdated = dsUpdated.Tables.Add();
dtUpdated = dsOriginal.Tables[0].Clone();
```

In the first line, you are declaring your object and initializing it to the result of an `Add` operation on the DataSet's Tables collection. In the second line, you are setting to to something else entirely!

`dtUpdated` may very well refer to the same object in memory as `dsUpdated.Tables[0]` after the first line of code, but the variable itself is not a constant reference to that object. Indeed, in the second line, you have set it to a different object, the result of another table's `Clone()` method. If the variable ever pointed to the same object as `dsUpdated.Tables[0]`, it does not anymore. It's similar to stating

```
int x = 5;
x = 6;
```

In the first line, the value of `x` is 5. In the second, you've replaced that value with 6. Similarly, with your table variable, the value is a reference. You've replaced one reference with another. Make sense?

Clone the table first, *then* add that table to the dataset. Now `dsUpdated.Tables[0]` will contain the cloned structure of `dsOriginal.Tables[0]` and your import should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
DataTable dt=dsOriginal.Tables[0].Clone(); 
dsUpdated.Tables.Add(dt);
DataTable dtUpdated=dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clone the `DataTable` first.

```
DataTable dt=table.Clone();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Select("AirAvail_Id=0"))
{                     
    dtAirAvail.ImportRow(row);
}
```

This will work fine.